# In Junit, is there a way I could have a TestSuite that adds a @ClassRule to each test class that is included

Tags: java, testing, junit, rule

For example, I have a test suite as such that collects a bunch of test classes that are listed in CreateObjectTests:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@ExcludeCategory({
    FailingTest.class,
    VolatileTest.class,
    PermissionTest.class
    })
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    CreateObjectTests.class
    })
public class CreateObjectTestRunner {}
```

CreateObjectTests.class uses ClasspathSuite to match maybe 20 different test classes. I want to be able to append a class rule that I have written (log in to CI server and do something) to each of the classes that are aggregated. i.e. I don't want to edit every single test class to add this @ClassRule for it to perform this functionality.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What will you do on the CI server? It almost sounds like something which should be outside the tests (for instance, in whatever you are using to run the tests - are you going to want this CI server action to be run in all environments; devs local machine, automated CI builds, etc)

Comment: Well I said CI server, but it just needs to make a REST call to a custom API, so it's definitely something that I want to be done in the execution of our tests. At this very moment, I've created my own custom runner that is very similar to the Suite class. The problem is that after it aggregates the tests, I can not trigger an API call at the end of a test class. It instead consideres the end of a test run the mement it finishes ALL tests; e.g. 5 tests from one class, 6 from another, instead of doing 5, API call, 6, API call, it'll do 11, API call.